# Генератор случайных ответов на PHP. Возможно ли это?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html

Как сделать генератор случайных ответов. Вообще возможно ли это на php? Аналог генератора случайных цифр. При условии содержания базы ответов в отдельном массиве.

Comment: Возможно. PHP - тьюринг-полный язык.  
Вопрос закрывается ввиду запутанной формулировки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделать это можно очень просто:

1. Учитывая, что у Вас имеется предопределенный массив с ответами, **узнаем длину этого массива**.
2. Декрементируем и **указываем в качестве максимального возможного значения** для сгенерированного числа.

Реализация может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
$data = array('answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3');
$maxValue = count($data) - 1;
$index = mt_rand(0, $maxValue);
$result = $data[$index];
```